# Get value from another df based on condition

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have 2 df

df1:

```
ID       X Y Cond
Johnson  2 3 fine
Sand     NAN NAN sick
Cooper   1 2 fine
Nelson   1 2 fine
Peterson 4 5 fine
```

and df2 :

```
id2      X Y 
Magic    2 3 
Sand     2 3 
Cooper   1 2 
Dean     1 2
```

I want to update x value in df1, if Cond ="sick" and df["id"] = df["id2]
to get the new df1 :

```
ID       X Y Cond
Johnson  2 3 fine
Sand     2 3  sick
Cooper   1 2 fine
Nelson   1 2 fine
Peterson 4 5 fine
```

I tried :

```
df1["x"] = np.where((df["cond"]=="sick")& (df1["id"]==df2["id2"]),df2["x"],"")
```

But its not working. I get this ValueError :

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First convert both `ID` columns to index values for possible match selected rows by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df11 = df1.set_index('ID')
df22 = df2.set_index('id2')

df11.loc[df11["Cond"]=="sick", ['X','Y']] = df22[['X','Y']]
df = df11.reset_index()
print (df)
         ID  X  Y  Cond
0   Johnson  2  3  fine
1      Sand  2  3  sick
2    Cooper  1  2  fine
3    Nelson  1  2  fine
4  Peterson  4  5  fine
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `where()` method of pandas dataframes instead of the `where`function from numpy. The code looks like this :

```
df1.loc[:,["X", "Y"]] = df1.loc[:,["X", "Y"]].where(df1["Cond"]!="sick",df2.loc[:,["X", "Y"]])
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not working. When running this code, I get this InvalidIndexError  : # slice me out of the other. Any idea ?

Comment: Check the case of the names of the columns. I use upper case for "X" and "Y"